# Double curly braces are rendered in page and are not replaced by bound value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm playing with an example in VS2012. I have the following html.

```
Name:
<br/>
<input type="text" data-ng-model="name"/> {{name}}
<script data-ng-src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
```

When running this, the curly braces with expression ({{ name }} are displayed on the page, this should not happen. When I type a name, the curly braces are not replaced with the value for name. What's the mistake that I make?

Answer (score 3):

initialize the app as a `angular app`

to do that

customize `html` tag as below

```
<html ng-app>
```

and remove `data-ng-src` and add `src` only

```
 <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
```